# Suppose $T,S$ are two non-identity elements in $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $TS=ST$. Then the number of fixed points of $S$ and $T$ are same.

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

What I could see is $T$ maps the fixed point set of $S$ to itself, so does $S$ for the fixed point set of $T$. But I can not proceed further. I was actually looking at the proof of a stronger result that says the fixed set is equal if and only if they commute. The proof uses the above statement. I seem to stuck to this point.

Comment: You meant $T,S$ are non-trivial. Go to $PGL_2(\Bbb{C})$, if possible diagonalize, find the elements commuting with $\pmatrix{a&0\\ 0&1}, a\in \Bbb{C}^*$, the other case is $\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}$, again find the elements commuting with it.

Comment: @reuns, Yes, I meant $S,T$ are non-identity.

Comment: @reuns, I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Im really just spelling out the comment of reuns in greater detail.

The fixed points of $S$ (resp. $T$) on $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb R}$ correspond to eigenvectors of (lifts of) $S$ (resp. $T$). This is because for $p \in \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$, one has

$$[Sp] = [p] \iff \text{there is } \lambda \neq 0 \text
{ such that } Sp = \lambda p.$$

Here, we use square brackets to denote the corresponding point in $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb R}$.

Can you show that the number of fixed points of $S$ (resp. $T$) is the number of eigenvalues of $S$ (resp. $T$)? (Here, you use that $S$ and $T$ are not the identity.)

Afterwards, compare eigenspaces of $S$ and $T$ using $ST = TS$.

Comment: You should update your answer by taking into account the possibility of complex eigenvalues.